# Salesforce rest api Events WhoId

Tags: salesforce

I am using salesforce rest api to pull meeting data.There is a field "WhoId" in the reponse which according to the documentation is the related lead or contact id .How do i find whether it is a lead or contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always tell what sort of object an ID corresponds to by [looking at the first 3 letters.](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html) In your case, you'd look for a prefix of `00Q` (Lead) or `003` (Contact).

See: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/1653

---

Backup copy of the full table [gisted](https://gist.github.com/mjball/1272f4e90612cd6394ac) (just in case!) and [rendered for your future convenience.](http://bl.ocks.org/mjball/raw/1272f4e90612cd6394ac/)

Comment: Generally it's true and in this example it'll work like a charm... but don't count on it being the absolute truth. If you have Chatter enabled "0D5" is a prefix for FeedItem, NewsFeed or UserProfileFeed tables, good luck with that ;)

Comment: @eyescream true, but at least the linked table mentions that.